# Recursive generic in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a class generator function that will allow me to add automatically some functionallity to other classes. The inheriting class has to put himself as generic when calling and extendig this generator. It was perfect until when i created an Interface Initialisable, that has to be implemented by all class inheriting from this generator. Basically for using this generator they have to implement the init method, i can effectively add an empty init method on the generated class, but i want the ts checker to aware the user in case it is not implemented.

The exported function:

```
interface Initialisable {
    init(): void | Promise<void>;
}

export default function Factory<T extends Initialisable>() {
    return class Factory {
        static instanceList: T[] = [];
        static createCount: number = 0;

        static create(): T {
            const instance =  new this();
            (instance as any).id = this.createCount++;

            (this as any).init();
            
            //@ts-ignore
            this.instanceList.push(instance);
            
            //@ts-ignore
            return instance;
        }

        static createList(amount = 0): T[] {
            const instanceList: T[] = [];

            for (let i=0; i<amount; i++) instanceList.push(this.create());

            return instanceList;
        }

        public readonly id = 0;

        public destroy(): void {
            (this.constructor as any).instanceList.splice((this.constructor as any).instanceList.indexOf(this), 1);
        }

    }
}
```

The test:
Problems:

Type 'Job' recursively references itself as a base type.
'Job' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own base expression

```
class Job extends Factory<Job>() {
    async init() {}
}
```

What i cannot get is that it works perfectly until i add this Interface requirement. Thanks!!!

//Edit

I always want to understand why it doesn't work with a T extends interface, but i found a way to make it work as same without using interfaces. We just have to make the generated class abstract and add the abstract init method and it works as intended.

```
export default function Factory<T>() {
abstract class Factory {
    
    //////

    abstract init(): void | Promise<void>;

    ///////

}

return Factory;
```

}

Comment: It's hard to answer "why" definitively. The compiler hits a loop when analyzing the types, so conceptually at least it's like "What's the type of `Job`? Does `Job` meet the `Initialisable` constraint? What's the type of `Job`'s `init()` method? Does it get any such method from `Factory<Job>`? What's the type of `Job`? Oops, circular." but the particulars depend on the specific of the type checker. This looks very similar to [ms/TS#40315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40315).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?